# Xamarin Main.axml changes don't show up in app

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

[image]
[image]

I've made a basic change to the background here, I changed the color to white.
But when i build and run the application in the emulator that comes with xamarin there are no changes at all, I also tried this with things like buttons and such. Some of the solutions i tried is rebuilding, regenerating resource.designer, remaking the project but nothing worked. Why isn't this working?

EDIT: Per request, Added the code for MainActivity.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Tresette
{
    [Activity(Label = "Tresette", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

And Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light" />
```

As you can see they are the default generated files with the addition of background in .axml file.

Comment: Maybe you use some style?( "android:Theme.Holo.Dark)

Comment: Just tried it, themes don't have an impact either :/

Comment: Sharing the content of MainActivity.cs and Main.axml (the source not design view) would be great

Comment: Added, they are the default files mostly tho.

Comment: Try add just "android:background="#FFFFFF""

Comment: Didn't work, the issue is that it simply seems to ignore the .axml file changes. Earlier when i tested putting the app fullscreen with c# code in the MainActivity.cs worked fine. But if I code everything manually that kinda defeats the purpose of using visual studio and stuff.

Comment: @simon101 Please, next time you comment in response to someone, add **@** symbol before his name, so that the user will receive a notification.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Sorry, my bad. I will put it in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are never using the Main.axml file. In your MainActivity.cs, the line that would set the layout is commented out:

`// SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);`

On Android, the `Activity` must select its layout or derive from something like `ListActivity` which has a built-in layout.

Comment: Ohhhh, damn I feel silly now. when I was working on desktop apps the vs layout was included by default so I didn't even consider it. Thanks!